# How can I combine multiple numpy arrays into a single memoryview for cython?

Tags: numpy, cython

I have a list of varying size that contains numpy arrays with the same data type and shape. I would like to process this data using a function written in Cython without copying the data. Both [memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#view-general-layouts) and the [Python buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html) seem to support this kind of data using indirect for the first dimension. So I was hoping that something like this could work:

```
%%cython
from cython.view cimport indirect
def test(list a):
    cdef double[::indirect, :] x
    x = a
    x[0, 0] = 42
```

Unfortunately it doesn't.

Is there a way to convert this list of numpy arrays into such a memoryview?

Comment: Sorry, can you give a little more context about what you're trying to do? Is `a` supposed to be a list of lists or something?

Comment: Oh I see, a list of numpy arrays. So you want to be able to represent ragged arrays in cython?

Comment: They are not jagged. The numpy arrays have all the same data type and shape. However the underlying data sits at irregular intervals in memory, so I cannot use a strided memoryview to represent it.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy way. This solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12991519/5769463) introduces its own container which make it possible to create indirect typed memory views. But I haven't tested it.